# Does jam have the halacha of duchka d'sakina?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, meat-and-milk

The Chochmas Odom in [49:9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33594&st=&pgnum=143) holds that all fruit have the halacha of duchka d'sakina, and that  if you cut a fruit with a meat knife which was not definitively clean, you need to scrape off the outer layer with a pareve knife in order to be able to treat the fruit as pareve.

Does jam have this halacha?  Would one need to scoop out any jam that came in contact with the knife?

Comment: Trying to understand.....the basis of your question is because of the soft (squishy) consistency of jam?

Comment: @Shokhet You're asking why I think it would be the same or why I think it would be different?  Either way, the answer is that I don't know why all fruit are considered comparable to a cucumber (the paradigm of Chullin 112a) and therefore don't know how far it extends.  Apples are much firmer than cucumbers.  Blueberries are much mushier.  So I'm just not sure.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the reason you thought jam might be different than regular fruit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point the Chochmas Adam is making is slightly different than you understood it. He is saying fruits that are not cured in brine do not have the law of duchka applicable to them, however being that they are juicy the grease from the knife sticks to the fruit, requiring the layer that contacted the knife to be disposed of.

This is seemingly only a din for a solid food, which can absorb, but still only absorb to certain depth. Anything liquid or mushed up would be subject to regular laws of taarovos.

Comment: This is _not_ a din of absorption.  The halacha of duchka d'sakina is a halacha of residue.  It applies to cold, non-charif foods where there are no b'lios.

Comment: @YEZ but in siff 9 he is no longer discussing the din of duchka. He is just clearing up a point left hanging. What if the fruit is not sharp from brine and duchka does not apply, now what? Answer is being that its juicy it absorbs a little bit and simply washing it will not help.